# Query taking long when i use user defined function with order by in oracle select

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function, which will get greatest of three dates from the table.

```
create or replace FUNCTION fn_max_date_val(
    pi_user_id IN number)
  RETURN DATE
IS
  l_modified_dt      DATE;
  l_mod1_dt  DATE;
  l_mod2_dt DATE;
  ret_user_id        DATE;
BEGIN

  SELECT MAX(last_modified_dt)
  INTO l_modified_dt
  FROM table1
  WHERE id = pi_user_id;
  -- this table contains a million records
  SELECT nvl(MAX(last_modified_ts),sysdate-90)
  INTO l_mod1_dt
  FROM table2
  WHERE table2_id=pi_user_id;
  -- this table contains clob data, 800 000 records, the table 3 does not have user_id and has to fetched from table 2, as shown below
  SELECT nvl(MAX(last_modified_dt),sysdate-90)
  INTO l_mod2_dt
  FROM table3
  WHERE table2_id IN
    (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE table2_id=pi_user_id
    );
  execute immediate 'select greatest('''||l_modified_dt||''','''||l_mod1_dt||''','''||l_mod2_dt||''') from dual' into ret_user_id;
  RETURN ret_user_id;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   return SYSDATE;
END;
```

this function works perfectly fine and executes within a second.

```
-- random user_id , just to test the functionality
SELECT fn_max_date_val(100) as max_date FROM DUAL 

MAX_DATE
--------
27-02-14
```

For reference purpose i have used the table name as table1,table2 and table3 but my business case is similar to what i stated below.

I need to get the details of the table1 along with the highest modified date among the three tables.

I did something like this.

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,a.value,fn_max_date_val(id) as max_date 
FROM table1 a where status_id ='Active';
```

The above query execute perfectly fine and got result in millisecods. But the problem came when i tried to use order by.

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,a.value,a.status_id,last_modified_dt,fn_max_date_val(id) as max_date 
FROM table1 where status_id ='Active' a 
order by status_id desc,last_modified_dt desc ;  
-- It took almost 300 seconds to complete
```

I tried using index also all the values of the status_id and last_modified, but no luck. Can this be done in a right way?

Comment: How many rows in the resultset ? Are you sure the sql client you use is not displaying only rownum <= X, so when you want an ordered set, all rows are processed and it takes time.

Comment: @Kobi . The result set with and without order by is same , almost 30k records are getting displayed.But the former takes more time.1) If i comment the function fn_max_date_val and run the query with order by it is executing fine, case 2) If i comment the order by and uncomment my function from my select query it is also executing fine.But not both.It is taking minimum 60 seconds to display the output.

Comment: any help? someone?

Comment: Have a look at execution plan for both query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about if your query is like this?

```
select a.*, fn_max_date_val(id) as max_date 
  from
    (SELECT a.id,a.name,a.value,a.status_id,last_modified_dt
       FROM table1 where status_id ='Active' a 
      order by status_id desc,last_modified_dt desc) a;
```

Comment: thanks.It worked, I have tried using with clause previously, but it was not working.This method works without error.

Answer (score 0):

What if you don't use the function and do something like this:

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,a.value,a.status_id,last_modified_dt x.max_date
FROM table1 a
(
  select max(max_date) as max_date
  from (
    SELECT MAX(last_modified_dt) as max_date
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE t1.id = a.id

    union

    SELECT nvl(MAX(last_modified_ts),sysdate-90) as max_date
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t2.table2_id=a.id

     ...
  ) y
) x
where a.status_id ='Active'
order by status_id desc,last_modified_dt desc;
```

Syntax might contain errors, but something like that + the third table in the derived table too.

Comment: Coz I need that as a a function, otherwise the cost of the single query is enormous.i used joins and combined all three tables as sub query and the cost went to 25k

Comment: Ok, so the query is fine as function now... and you don't have any problems?

Comment: Select query combined with the user defined function and order by clause is taking 30 second -210 seconds..If either my user-defined function or order by clause is commented then my query is getting executed in less than a second..From the beginning the problem is to make both applicable without compromising the time..

Comment: That's not related to my answer or your first comment to the answer in any way.